# Strategies to find easy isomorphism between basics groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I am currently taking introduction to algebra and I am struggling to find rapidly isomorphism between groups. I know my question is a bit broad in a sense that there is no singular answers but I find it cumbersome to find (1) a potential isomorphism and (2) to verify that this potential isomorphism is indeed an isomorphism. For example, one kind question that I struggle with ; Show two isomorphisms between U(20) and U(16). What I would do in practice is list the order of each elements of these groups and construct an isomorphism such that elements of same order map to each other but in an exam, I wouldn't have the time to do so. To conclude, is there some kind of aptitude that I should master to spot isomorphisms quickly?

Thank you very much

Comment: Generators and relations. If you can find generators and relations for one of the groups, and then find generators of the other group that satisfy the same relations, then you have an isomorphism taking the generators of the one group to the corresponding generators of the other group.

Comment: Did that help? Can you find generators and relations for, say, the group of units modulo $20$, and then find corresponding generators in the group of units modulo $16$ that satisfy the same relations?

Comment: U(20) is not cyclic

Comment: Groups have generators, whether they are cyclic or not. A group is cyclic if it can be generated by a single element. If it isn't cyclic, that just means it needs two or more generators. E.g., the group of permutations of a three-element set is generated by the pair, $(1\ 2\ 3)$ and $(1\ 2)$.

Comment: oh I see thank you, that help so much. Just to make sure, to verify that a combinations of generators effectively generate a group you effectuate the internal direct product of the of the groups formed by these generators?

Comment: No. If you're using the term, "direct product", the same way I use it, you only get things of the form $(a^r,b^s)$, where $a$ and $b$ are generators. But you need things of the form $a^rb^sa^tb^u\dots b^z$ – you need the smallest group containing both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: yes this is what internal product is! Thank you very much!